# Creating a contact list from SQL Database

Tags: php, sql

I am looking to query my database based on what the user would like to search by: Ex. (Zip, City, State, Name, Etc Etc).  Let's say I search by zip code, and there are 2 results in my SQL for that zip code.

I would like the results to be displayed in the following format on my webpage:

```
Company Name
Address
City, State Zip
Contact Us Link                     Link to Another Page
```

I use the following code for something similar but I display the results in a table with check-boxes.

```
    <?php
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            echo '<tr><td>';
            echo '<input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" value="'.$row['order_number'].'"/>';
            echo '</td>';
            foreach ($row as $key => $value)
                echo '<td>'.htmlspecialchars($value).'</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
    ?>
```

I really would like to display the results of the search in the format I explained above.  I am lost on how to get the results I want.  Any help is much appreciated!!

Thanks

Would it be possible to do this as well:

If the Company Name row in my SQL is blank/empty, skip over that row/entry and go to the next.

Comment: What about the infamous < address > tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do, is pull each piece of information individually from the resulting row (change the fields based on what you pull from the table):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
   echo htmlspecialchars($row['comp_name']) . '<br />';
   echo htmlspecialchars($row['Address']) . '<br />';
   echo $row['city'] . ', ' . $row['zip'] . '<br />';
   echo '<a href="mailto:' . $row['contact'] . '">Contact us</a><a href="index.php">Some link</a>';//If it's an email
}
```

or for table output

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
   echo '<table>'
   echo '<tr><td colspan="2">' . htmlspecialchars($row['comp_name']) . '</td></tr>';
   echo '<tr><td colspan="2">' . htmlspecialchars($row['Address']) . '</td></tr>';
   echo '<tr><td colspan="2">' . $row['city'] . ', ' . $row['zip'] . '<br />';
   echo '<tr><td><a href="mailto:' . $row['contact'] . '">Contact us</a></td><td>a href="index.php">Some linke</a></td></tr>';
   echo '</table>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are wanting to list the information, you could use an `<ul>` and output each row as `<li>`.

```
<style>
ul { list-style: none; }
</style>

<?php
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){             
    echo "<ul>";
    echo "<li>".$row["companyName"]."</li><li>".$row["address"]."</li><li>".$row["city"].", ".$row["state"]." ".$row["zipcode"]."</li>";
    echo "<li><a href=\"contact.html\">Contact Us</a></li><ul>";
}
?>
```

Also, what is the "Link to Another page"?